# Find next DOM element with React testing library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

Here is the HTML structure of the component I would like to test

```
  <body>
    <div>
      <div>
        <fieldset>
          <label>
            <span>
              Start date
            </span>
          </label>
          <input
            type="date"
            value="10.11.2020"
          />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <label>
            <span>
              End date
            </span>
          </label>
          <input
            type="date"
            value="22.12.2022"
          />
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

What I would like to do is find the start and end date input tags and click them.

I unfortunately cannot change this mark up - I cannot add for example `data-testid="start-input"` to the first input tag

The RTL documentation says I should try and find elements by either text or by their role - So I can find the fieldsets role or, what I've been trying to do is this - finding the labels text and then try to get the closest input element, so this;

```
const DateRange = renderComponent();
const StartDateInput = DateRange.getByText('Start date').closest('input');
```

console logging `StartDateInput` returns `null` - If I remove `.closest('input')` I have the label tag element so that part is correct up to that point at least

I couldn't find any RTL documentation on how to do this - if anyone knows of any and can point me in the right direction that would be amazing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my question is possible (I'd love someone to tell me if it is) ... but I did find a way around the issue

Simply search for the DOM / HTML element by display value

```
const StartDateInput = DateRange.getByDisplayValue('2020-11-11');
```

Just a note that this will NOT work with the code in the original question as I wanted to illustrate an error I made which burnt up A LOT of time for me

In my test I had set the mockStart and mockEnd dates as so

```
let mockStartDate = '11.11.2020';
let mockEndDate = '11.11.2022';
```

This resulted in the test telling me 'Unable to find an element with the display value: 11.11.2020' because this is an invalid date format ... updating the strings to this fixed the issue;

```
let mockStartDate = '2020-11-11';
let mockEndDate = '2022-11-11';
```